# dark mode not changing gray background

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello when trying to make a dark mode I use the dark mode class but with the light gray background in some parts of the website it does not work, how can I get those backgrounds to change to dark gray or black when dark mode is enabled

```css
.dark-mode {
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
    }

.light-grey {
    color: #000!important;
    background-color: #f1f1f1!important;
}
```

```js
<script>
// On page load set the theme.
(function() {
  let onpageLoad = localStorage.getItem("theme") || "";
  let element = document.body;
  element.classList.add(onpageLoad);
  document.getElementById("theme").textContent = localStorage.getItem("theme") || "light";
})();

function themeToggle() {
  let element = document.body;
  element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");

  let theme = localStorage.getItem("theme");
  if (theme && theme === "dark-mode") {
    localStorage.setItem("theme", "");
  } else {
    localStorage.setItem("theme", "dark-mode");
  }

  document.getElementById("theme").textContent = localStorage.getItem("theme");
}
</script>
```

Regular mode:
[image]

What it looks like when adding dark mode:
[image]

Comment: I guess this is because of `!important`, but please post your HTML to make sure. BTW you might use user's system dark mode preference instead of the custom switch. I'd suggest you read on CSS selectors specificity and `prefers-dark-mode` media query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 'toggle' just on body tag.
So you need add this in your CSS:

```
.dark-mode .light-grey{ /* what you want */  }
```

Comment: I did try that but still get the same result as listed above

Comment: Anyone else have any ideas

Comment: .light-grey has 'important', so ".dark-mode .light-grey" also need to add "important", its weight will be stronger than .light-grey .

Or you can delete 'important' of .light-grey

Answer (score 0):

not sure about the whole context but if I were to do this in vanilla CSS I would create seperate selectors for the different background colors so I can just switch out the class names in the html elements

```css
div {
width: 200px
height: 200px
}

.dark-mode {
        color: white;
 }
    
    
  /* This is selector is basically saaying when you see these two class applied together on the same element apply this style: */
 .dark-mode.gray-background { 
  background-color: gray 
  }
  
  .dark-mode.black-background {
  background-color: black
  }

.light-grey {
    color: #000!important;
    background-color: #f1f1f1!important;
}
```

```html
<!-- in the html the backgrounds will be different -->
<div className="dark-mode gray-background"></div>

<div className="dark-mode black-background"></div>
```

Comment: the context of this is when enabling dark mode the gray does not change to dark mode so how can I get it to change with it

Comment: What are you storing in localStorage? Is it the css itself?

Comment: The cookies of their preference of which theme they prefer seems to work for me